# How to set both enable assertions and heap size in MAVEN_OPTS in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, maven, command-line

The following batch does not run

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-ea -Xmx16g"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="tests.Runner01"
```

error is

```
Unrecognized option: -ea -Xmx16g
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How to overcome?

Comment: have you tried nesting the single quotes into double quotes (or vice versa)?
set MAVEN_OPTS='"-ea -Xmx16g"'

Comment: does it work if you don't go crazy with the max heap flag? E.g. try -Xmx4g ? Maybe the amount of memory required is simply not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `maven_home/bin/mvn.bat`:

> @REM MAVEN_OPTS - parameters passed to the Java VM when running Maven
>   @REM     e.g. to debug Maven itself, use
>    @REM set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug
>   -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
>     ....
>   **%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath ....**

In this example you can see that options are set without quotes, so you should use

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-ea -Xmx16g
```

JVM will be started with

```
java -ea -Xmx16g -classpath ...
```

command in this case, that is correct.

**But**, when you define `MAVEN_OPTS="-ea -Xmx16g"` then JVM will be started with command

```
java "-ea -Xmx16g" -classpath ...
```

that is invalid statement